# Can I add a where conditon to this joins $x->getTable1()->getTable2()?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Can I add a where conditon to this joins `$x->getTable1()->getTable2()` to have a result same as this query:

```
$y = Doctrine_Query::create()  
      ->from('Table0 t0')
      ->innerJoin('t0.Table1 t1')
      ->innerJoin('t1.Table2 t2')
      ->where('t2.status = "active"')
      ->execute->getLast();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom method. I usually do this thing like this.

In Table1.class.php, create a custom method:

```
public function getTable2ByStatus($status = 'active')
{
  return Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table2')->retrieveByStatus($status);
}
```

Then, in Table2Table.class.php:

```
public function retrieveByStatus($status)
{
  return $this->createQuery('t2')
    ->where('t2.status = ?', $status)
    ->execute()
    ->getLast();
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
$x->getTable1()->getTable2ByStatus();
```